# C: can't figure out what is causing an infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

I'm a beginner, and as an exercise I have to code a very simple calculator that modifies the stack by the number and the operator the user inputs.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   long double x, stack = 0;
   char op;

   printf("Input an operator and a number:\n");

   while ( op != 'q' )
   {
      scanf("%Lf %c", &x, &op);
      switch (op)   
      {
      case '+':
         stack += x;
         printf("= %Lg", stack);
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case '-':
         stack -= x;
         printf("= %Lg", stack);
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case '*':
         stack *= x;
         printf("= %Lg", stack);
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case '/':
         if (x == 0)
         { 
            printf("Can't divide by 0.");
            printf("\n");
            break;
         }
         stack /= x;
         printf("= %Lg", stack);
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 's':
         stack = x;
         printf("stack set to %Lg", x);
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 'q':
         printf("Bye!\n");
         break;
      default:
         printf("Unknown operator.\n");
         break;
      }
   }

   printf("Bye!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever `x` is not an number, the program keeps looping. Why?

And how could I prevent the user from inputing anything but a number for `x`? If `x` was a `char` I'd use `isdigit()`, but that's not the case.

(By the way, I want `x` to be a `long double` so I can input numbers with decimals).

Comment: FYI, you have undefined behavior before the very first iteration of your loop. `op != 'q'` is tested while `op` is still uninitialized.

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: And there is no reason for the second printf in each case, just have the \n be part of the first: printf("= %Lg\n", stack);

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ. And I knew that, SoronelHaetir, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @ToritoVerdejo .. so why did you not fix it before posting here and wasting users' time telling you stuff you already know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` will convert as many values from the string as it can. If one cannot be converted, it stops processing the string. Either way, the function returns a value indicating how many values were converted.

If the first value (`x`) is not a number and cannot be converted, it stops. And so the second value (`op`) does not change. That causes your loop to continue.

Check the value returned by `scanf()` to confirm this behavior yourself.

Also, *"I want x to be a long double so I can input numbers with decimals"* - Values of type `float` and `double` also support numbers with decimals.

Finally, as others have point out, you should initialize `op` at the start of your code before testing if it equals "q". This will ensure the value is what you expect it to be at that time.

Comment: I think the final paragraph should have been the first.

Comment: @machine_1: I don't think it should be first because that wasn't what he was asking, and it would not cause the issue he is asking about. I answered his question first, then pointed out other issues afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got it. (PS: I knew the last thing you said. I just mentioned it to make clear I don't want to use anything that was not a float or a double).

Comment: @ToritoVerdejo: I already told you. Check the return value of `scanf()`. If it wasn't able to convert any values, then there was something wrong with the way the values was entered.

Comment: OK, I thought that was just to check how `scanf()` works. Thank you again.